# Annotation value from application.propeties for @MongoEntity

Tags: annotations, quarkus

I am specifying a @MongoEntity collection name as follows:

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "collection_name_from_properties")
```

but I'd like to specify it from the application.properties file, like I do for a class property:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "application_property_param")
String myConfigParam;
```

I've tried without luck in the same way I do in Spring:

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "${collection_name_from_properties}")
```

Any Idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: As far As I know this is not possible, the only thing that is being read from the properties file regarding this annotation is the database, not the collection name, why do you want to have dynamic collection names?

Comment: Here you can check the documentation of the annotation https://javadoc.io/static/io.quarkus/quarkus-mongodb-panache/1.2.0.CR1/io/quarkus/mongodb/panache/MongoEntity.html

Comment: @JavierToja In case the collection names need to be changed on mongo db, I need to be able to update the names via application.properties, without the need to release a new version of the client.
Documentation does not help.

Comment: Well, you only choice is use plain POJOS and have all your collection names in a property file, then in your DAO layer make the binding of each collection name and POJO class for your model, but forget about using panache, go just plain mongo client

Answer (score 0):

`@MongoEntity` is a relatively new feature to Quarkus, and so as far as I know there is no way to accomplish this using Panache.

If you want to use Panache, the best you could do is hard code all the collections names for the time being until a new update potentially resolves this.

I would, however, recommend that you use the Mongo Client if you need more advanced Mongo operations.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late but maybe it helps someone else.
You have an extra character "$".
Instead of

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "${collection_name_from_properties}")
```

It should work like this

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "{collection_name_from_properties}")
```